# Has anyone experienced these lines on your film?

Tags: film, scanning

I noticed these parallel lines/streaks across my film. This was shot on a Mamiya RZ67 and I've never really experienced these lines before. Got the film developed at a local film lab, and self-scanned. I was able to rule out the scanner as the issue as I tried two different scanners and still saw the lines. Is this a development issue? Or is it an issue with my camera? Hoping that someone out there has experienced this and solved it! Thank you in advance :)
[image]

Best,
Dante

Comment: What happens if you turn it 90 degrees and scan again? (On either scanner?) Can you see the lines on the actual negatives when looking at them back-illuminated through a loupe or magnifying glass?

Comment: What 2 scanners?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Film emulsions are affected by pressure. As film is advanced in camera, its path brings it in contact with rollers. These are steel with polished surfaces. Dirt and grit can adhere. When this happens, the surface of the film is lightly scratched and this action acts much like an exposure. In other words, streaks are seen in the developed film.  The remedies are to clean the rollers and lightly lubricate them so that they turn freely.

Pressure marks can also result from poor maintenance of the film developing machine. Modern photofinishers often develop film in a roller transport film processor. The cassette is loaded into the machine and the tongue of the film is attached to a “leader card”. The entry door is closed, and the film is pulled over a series of rollers. The path is into the developer tank, then over and out to another and then several more fluid filled tanks. Eventually the film enters a drying chamber.

These marks are pressure marks. The culprit can be the cassette, the camera, or the developing machine. Pressure marks come in two flavors depending on when the pressure is applied and the amount of pressure. Usually, if received before processing they add density to the film. If received during the developing process, the emulsion is disturbed, and this changes the time required for the chemicals of the process to enter and exit. These lines (marks) will be less dense than the surrounds.